# Collect summaries with optimize_loss function just from variables in specific scope

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am fine-tuning deep network that consists of two parts: pre-trained inception residual network at the top and my new random-initialized layers at the bottom. I am using **optimize_loss** function form `contrib.layers` module for training. It also provide summary collection of weight or gradient distributions but it is quite slow to do it for whole network.

Is it possible to collect these summaries through this function just from my new added layers that I have in separate name scope?

```
   optimize = layers.optimize_loss(loss = self.loss_err,
                                   global_step = self.global_step,
                                   learning_rate = 0.001,
                                   summaries = layers.optimizers.OPTIMIZER_SUMMARIES,
                                   optimizer = optimizer,
                                   clip_gradients = 2)
```